# SQL Grouping where the row order matters... possible?

Tags: sql, oracle

You group by things that are the same...  can I group by things that are consecutive?  I have a machine which has a tool and the tool is used for a few jobs, then it comes off the machine, I get another tool, it runs, then the first tool comes back.  I want to three records, not two even though there are only two tools.

Imagine your data looks like this:

```
Select
'1' as Machine,
'A' as Tool,
'ZZ' as Product,
sysdate as Start_date,
sysdate+(6/24) as End_Date
from dual
union all
Select
'1' as Machine,
'A' as Tool,
'QQ' as Product,
sysdate+(6/24) as Start_date,
sysdate+(12/24) as End_Date
from dual
union all
Select
'1' as Machine,
'B' as Tool,
'WW' as Product,
sysdate+(12/24) as Start_date,
sysdate+(18/24) as End_Date
from dual
UNION ALL
Select
'1' as Machine,
'A' as Tool,
'QQ' as Product,
sysdate+(18/24) as Start_date,
sysdate+1 as End_Date
from dual
```

And you want to write a SQL query that results in this:

```
+---------------+------------+------------+
|     Machine   |    Tool    |   Run_time |
+---------------+------------+------------+
|     1         |    A       |     12 hrs |
|     1         |     B      |     6 hrs  |
|     1         |     A      |     6 hrs  |
+---------------+------------+------------+
```

NOT this:

```
+---------+------+----------+
| Machine | Tool | Run_time |
+---------+------+----------+
| 1       | A    | 18 hrs   |
| 1       | B    | 6 hrs    |
+---------+------+----------+
```

This is an Oracle DB if that matters.

Comment: What did you try as sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a "trick" that uses differences in `row_number()`:

```
select machine, tool, sum(end_date - start_date)*24 as run_time_hours
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by machine order by start_date) -
              row_number() over (partition by machine, tool order by start_date)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by grp, machine, tool;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/26107) is a SQL Fiddle.

I'll let you work out how this works.  Your sample is small enough that you can do the calculations for the row numbers quite easily.

Comment: My real data is small enough too... only 1500 machine/tool changes so it works perfectly.  I would never have thought to subtract one rank from another to make a pseudo group.  That's really good!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can group by consecutive elements with analytics. For instance, you can create a "grouping" column by using a running total over a column that takes a value only when there is a gap (switch in tool):

```
SQL> SELECT machine, tool, SUM(time_hr)
  2    FROM (SELECT machine, tool, time_hr, start_date,
  3                 SUM(gap) OVER(PARTITION BY machine
  4                                   ORDER BY start_date) usage_group
  5             FROM (SELECT machine, tool, start_date,
  6                          (end_date - start_date) * 24 time_hr,
  7                           CASE
  8                              WHEN tool != LAG(tool)
  9                                              OVER(PARTITION BY machine
 10                                                       ORDER BY start_date)
 11                              THEN 1
 12                              ELSE
 13                               0
 14                           END gap
 15                      FROM DATA))
 16   GROUP BY machine, tool, usage_group
 17   ORDER BY MIN(start_date);

MACHINE TOOL SUM(TIME_HR)
------- ---- ------------
1       A              12
1       B               6
1       A               6
```

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers!  Never heard of LAG but that is VERY INTERESTING.  We do lots of silly VB here to write rows and hold some value to compare to the next row, and if so, make a change.  LAG seems to make that completely unnecessary.